# Probability of getting any matching pair of 2 cards when x cards are drawn from a deck

Tags: probability

A 60 card deck has 4 1a, 1b, 2a, 2b, 3a, 3b, 4a, and 4b cards (32 in total) and 28 blank cards. When x cards are drawn, what are the chances that at least 1 of any of the four pairs are drawn (such as drawing both a 1a and 1b or a 3a and two 3bs). It should be 100% above 44 and 0% below 2.

How do I arrive at the answer to it? I've tried several equations but they've gotten close, not exactly correct.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Are the blanks considered pairs?

Comment: No it's a curiosity of mine for a card game. The blanks aren't considered pairs, they just take up space.

Comment: It would appear that this has been answered recently:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239746/what-is-the-probability-of-drawing-a-four-of-a-kind-when-20-cards-are-drawn-from